# VBA function not referring to correct sheet

Tags: function, vba, excel

I'm making a data parser in VBA for chart output in another program.  I made this vba code and it's not referring to the correct ranges.

Here is the function:

```
Function HCAlt(Rng1 As Range, Rng2 As Range, Rng3 As Range, Rng4 As Range) As String
' this function will take columns of data and properly format them for highcharts scatter pairs
Dim retVal As String
Dim i As Integer
Dim startRow As Integer
startRow = Rng1.Row

'if ranges doesn't contains one column and same rows count - return #VALUE error
If Rng1.Rows.count <> Rng2.Rows.count Or _
    Rng1.Columns.count <> 1 Or Rng2.Columns.count <> 1 Or Rng3.Rows.count <> Rng2.Rows.count Then
    HCAlt = CVErr(xlErrValue)
    Exit Function
End If

For i = 0 To Rng1.Rows.count - 1
    retVal = retVal & "{x:" & Rng3.Cells(startRow + i, 1) & ",y:" & Rng4.Cells(startRow + i, 1) & ",samp:'" & Rng1.Cells(startRow + i, 1) & "'" & ",Rock:'" & Rng2.Cells(startRow + i, 1) & "'},"
Next i
'remove last comma
If retVal <> "" Then retVal = Left(retVal, Len(retVal) - 1)

HCAlt = "[" & retVal & "]"
End Function
```

The cell that calls the function is this code:

```
 HCAlt(INDIRECT(M$47),INDIRECT(M46),INDIRECT(M65),INDIRECT(M61))
```

The cells it is referring to are ranges:

```
 Cell M46= PlotData!R55:R141  'this is a range on sheet "PlotData"
 Cell M47= PlotData!A55:A141  'this is a range on sheet "PlotData"
 Cell M61= StData!L55:L141    'this is a range on sheet "StData"
 Cell M65= StData!P55:P141    'this is a range on sheet "StData"
```

The function "works" but it's not referring to the cells I want it to (it's giving me back garbage data).

Do I need to declare the sheets it's referring to?  or is the range value in the indirect port over to tell the function what sheet to find it?

Thanks

Comment: I've come across some methods in Excel that work much better using R1C1 notation.  I can't comment specifically on your code as I haven't tried it.  You might try checking that the range address in your function matches the addresses you are passing into the function.

Comment: Everything seems to be fine. If these sheets exist, they are referred to correctly. Try setting a breakpoint and looking at the values in interactrive debug.

Comment: How can I see which sheet it's looking on.  When I run through with breakpoint I'm getting data that doesn't match up.

Comment: Add watches for `Rng1-Rng4` and maybe some other vars. It's hard for me to say what's wrong because I don't know what you are expecting this function to return and what it actually returns.

Comment: Here's something that may help explain the issue.  I can see that when my range is from 55 to 141, I'm getting data from row 109 and not row 55.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here was my problem.  I thought I needed to "start" on the row at which the range started.  In my example it was 55, so I made a variable to get that row and then added it to the cell row.

```
Dim startRow As Integer
startRow = Rng1.Row

Rng3.Cells(startRow + i, 1) '  this is part of the code where I added this starting row- see above'
```

I deleted the starting row variable and used this instead:

```
Rng3.Cells(i, 1)
```

Since my data was referring to "duplicated" tables of the same data that was sorted differently, I could change the cells I was referring to so they were all on the same sheet.

```
Cell M46= StData!R55:R141  'this is a range on sheet "StData"
Cell M47= StData!A55:A141  'this is a range on sheet "StData"
Cell M61= StData!L55:L141  'this is a range on sheet "StData"
Cell M65= StData!P55:P141  'this is a range on sheet "StData"
```

This worked out with the proper values. I'm not sure if the last part made any difference, but I'm playing it safe.